# Google App Engine, JDO, use Date in filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore, java.util.date

In my application, I would like to fetch a set of entities from the Datastore, that have a Date field set to a date before the present moment.

I do realize, that one of the ways of doing that is by simply storing the date in those entities as just a `long` value in milliseconds.

But ist there actually a way of storing them as `Date`s and being able to use them for filtering?

I tried something like 
`query.setFilter("dateField.before(dateParam)");` , but it didnt work, neither did the simple comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply declare the `dateField` as `java.util.Date`, then use

```
query.setFilter("dateField < dateParam");
query.declareParameters("java.util.Date dateParam");
List<...> results = (List<...>) query.execute(new java.util.Date());
```

See examples here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html

Answer (score 1):

Constantin's solutions gives:

> Operator  <  cannot be used as part of the join condition.

Adding a colon before parameter name made it work for me:

```
q.setFilter("createdTime < :nowTime");
List<...> result = (List<...>) q.execute(new java.util.Date());
```